# can I use any annotation on custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations

As, I know we can apply annotation like `@Target`, `@Retention`, `@Documented` on custom annotation.

But recently I saw @Constraint applied on custom annotation.

Can We use any annotation on custom annotation? how it works?

Comment: You can define what your annotation can be applied to using the annotation `@Target`. To be applicable to other annotations, you can annotate that annotation with `@Target({{ANNOTATION_TYPE})`

Comment: The concept you're looking for is *meta-annotation*.

Answer (score 0):

Each annotation can only be written in certain places.  Those places are determined by the [`@Target`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) meta-annotation on the annotation's definition.  For example, if an annotation is declared as

```
    @Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
    public @interface MyAnnotation {
        ...
    }
```

then `@MyAnnotation` may only be written on annotation declarations.  You cannot write `@MyAnnotation` on a field or class declaration, or on a type use.  An annotation that may be written on annotation declarations is called a meta-annotation.

You can learn more about annotations from the [Java annotations tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).